# Minimal type annotation for Array.prototype.filter and discriminated union?

Tags: typescript, filter, functional-programming

Consider the snippet below:

```
type asdf = '.' | number;
const foo: asdf[] = ['.', 1, 3, '.'];
const bar: number[] = foo.filter(v => typeof v === 'number');
```

It fails compilation, since the compiler cannot deduce that the type of `bar` is `number[]`.

1. Why cannot the compiler deduce the correct type?
2. What is the minimal type annotations to make the compiler understand the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to achieve this.

A type guard is a function which takes in an item `v` and asserts that it is type `Foo`. In your example, your type guard will look like this:

```
function isNumber(value: asdf): value is number {
    return typeof value === "number";
}
```

You will then pass that value into your `filter` function like so:

```
const bar: number[] = foo.filter(isNumber);
```

If you'd like to keep your function inline, you can do it like this (but I think it's a bit less clear):

```
const bar: number[] = foo.filter((item): item is number => typeof item === "number");
```

Your code was not working because you didn't have the `item is number` part - that tells the compiler that if the assertion (`typeof item === "number"`) returns true, then `item` is of type `number`.

Comment: the inline version was **exactly** the kind of solution I hoped for. many thanks!